# Selecting with function in codeigniter active records without using the $this->db->query()

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Hi I'm starting to query my database in codeigniter and everything is working fine on a basic select statement but after I added my sql functions everything turns down. Well basically I have a function to Propercase text in mysql which  supposed to work like this:

```
SELECT proper(foo_bar) as foo from foo;
```

this one should return something like this:

```
|Foo    |
|Foo Bar|
```

Now applying the active records I expected it to be like this:

```
$this->db->select('proper(foo_bar)');
$query = $this->db->get('foo');
```

Well I still don't know the part of aliasing but I need to solve this one for now but yes there is no return after this query. I think the CI read it as

```
Select 'proper(foo_bar)' from foo
```

which is obviously totally wrong. 
And by the way, as much as possible I don't want to manually key in my query like this:

```
 $query = $this->db->query("SELECT proper(foo_bar) as foo from foo");
```

that would be impractical in my opinion. Any way to solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by doc you should pass a second parameter to avoid field protection with backticks.

```
$this->db->select('proper(foo_bar) AS propfoo',FALSE);
```

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html#select

Comment: but the document also states that "This is useful if you need a compound select statement." I think that is a select as column inside a select. And, uhh, I tried it and it's not working. :)

Comment: haha, and I missed out some lines too. now it works! but I think I will need to sacrifice the protection. Hope someday a proper way will surfaced for this. Thanks for the help! :)